# CQ5 - Get DAM image width and height for programmatic use

Tags: jsp, jstl, adobe, aem, dam

I have images in the DAM in CQ5 and I need to access the width and height of these images inside a .jsp for programmatic use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [AssetDetails](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/ref/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/resource/details/AssetDetails.html) class to get the details of a particular DAM Asset.

For e.g.,

```
Resource res = resourceResolver.getResource("<<path to resource>>"); 
AssetDetails assetDetails = new AssetDetails(res);
assetDetails.getHeight();
assetDetails.getWidth();
```